# Angular Not Display Font Awesome Icons

Tags: angular, typescript, icons, font-awesome

I've installed font awesome and added the FontAwesomeModule to the imports for app.module.ts. I'm trying to add an icon to a component within this module and it still says that "fa-icon" is not a known element:

"'fa-icon' is not a known element:

1. If 'fa-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'fa-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message."

All of the answers I see out there are because the FontAwesomeModule isn't added to the imports of the module containing the component and icon. This isn't the case and I'm looking for the reason why it is still not recognized.

courses.component.html:

```
<div class="course">
 <h3>{{ course.title }}</h3>
 <fa-icon icon="{{ faCoffee }}"></fa-icon>
 <p>Students: {{ course.students | number }}</p>
 <p>Rating: {{ course.rating | number: ".2-2" }}</p>
 <p>Price: {{ course.price | currency: "USD":true:".2-2" }}</p>
 <p>Release Date: {{ course.releaseDate | date: "shortDate" }}</p>
 <p>Description: <span class="desc">{{ course.description | summary }}</span></p>
 <button (click)="fullDesc()" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</button>
</div>
```

courses.component.ts:

```
import { CoursesService } from './../courses.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses',
  templateUrl: './courses.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses.component.css']
})
export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit {
  faCoffee = faCoffee;
  course = {
  title: "The Complete Music Course",
  rating: 4.434,
  students: 32354,
  price: 132.99,
  releaseDate: new Date(2016, 4, 1),
  description: "The Music Theory course is designed to enhance music skills and basic music fundamentals. Throughout the course of the year students will study basic notation, scales, key signatures, intervals, triads, cadences, non-chord tones, form, part-writing and analysis of a score."
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { SummaryPipe } from './summary.pipe';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  CoursesComponent,
  SummaryPipe
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  FormsModule,
  FontAwesomeModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add a new framework to the Angular application you will have to restart the angular lite server.

Try restarting the angular server and clearing the browser cache.
If you are using Chrome, then check the "Disable cache" in the developer tools.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I was a little skeptical because I was seeing the message in VSCode not the broswer but now I can see the icons on the page. I am still seeing the issue in VSCode though. Is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: Most likely it is the issue with caching. I always disable the cache while I develop front end applications. Could you please explain me the issue in VSCode?

Comment: If the error shows up in the VS Code then try restarting VSCode and the angular lite server.

Comment: If you see my inital post, it shows the exact error message from VSCode. Starting with "'fa-icon' is not a known element: ..." Thats the error I'm still having there.

Comment: Restarting both VSCode and restarting the server after installing font awesome has solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to reinstall it, it's not taking too much time.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome

Comment: Just reinstalled, same issue.

Comment: Can you try open the link above, go to "Compatibility table" section to make sure you installed a suitable version base on your Angular version

Comment: The Problem remains

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VSCode solved the issue for my case.

as proposed by @[anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15783793/anthony) in the comments